# How to scroll the edittext inside the scrollview

Tags: android, user-interface, scrollview

I have a scrollview inside which there is a editext which is **multiline**. I want to scroll the edittext to see the lower content but it can't be done.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="View Complaint"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="20dp" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="Order Number 0100C1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Name of ClientClient 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Subject : Measurement Issues"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sapien etiam, nunc amet dolor ac odio mauris justo. Luctus arcu, urna praesent at id quisque ac. Arcu massa vestibulum malesuada, integer vivamus el/ eu "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="Assign to"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:entries="@array/array_name" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="#eeeeee"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="Android applications normally run entirely on a single thread by              default the “UI thread” or the “main thread”.
        
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" ></EditText>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Comment History"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="147dp"
                android:src="@drawable/adddd" />
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Close Complaints"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ll"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/login_btn"
                android:text="Submit"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Can you guys help me in that . I think editText is getting the focus when cursor is inside it.

Thanks..!!!!!

Comment: This is a structural problem with having a scrolling EditText within a ScrollView. Since you have the ScrollView just allow the EditText to grow in height as needed.. no EditText scrollbar required.  This reminds me of frustrating web pages that have a scrolling iFrame that is taller than the browser window. Hope you found a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Try this..

Add below lines into your `EditText`

```
android:overScrollMode="always"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

**Example**

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="Android applications normally run entirely on a single thread by              default the “UI thread” or the “main thread”."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
    </EditText>
```

**EDIT**

Programmatically

```
youredittext.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (youredittext.hasFocus()) {
               v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
               switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
                      v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                      return true;
                }
             }
             return false;
       }
});
```

Comment: by xml way when i touch inside the edittext then softkeyboard opens but after implementing the programtically keyboard also refuses to come. In both the cases there is no scroll inside the editText.

Comment: The XML method never worked for me, and a previous version of the programmatic method worked but also prevented the soft keyboard from showing. The programmatic method was updated on August 11 and it now works flawlessly for me.

Comment: Use both, in xml as well as programmatically, it works

Comment: THANKS it is working but one issue occurred it makes my text font too small.have you any solution for it ?

Comment: Thanks, man this works perfectly when I add these properties in XML but my case is that I am creating edit text dynamically, now the issue is that the scroll bar is not showing just even I have changed the color of the scrollbar but no luck.

Comment: Thanks! Programmatic solution works. See Kotlin solutions below. Also `performClick()` or `@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")` can be added.

Comment: The XML doesn't work for me BUT the programmatic method worked perfectly for me. +1 -- Cheers!

Answer (score 74):

First add this at XML

```
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:scrollbars="vertical" 
android:overScrollMode="always"
```

Then add the same above "OnTouch" but make it return "false" not "true"

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

                    if (view.getId() == R.id.DwEdit) {
                        view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        switch (event.getAction()&MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
}
```

Comment: when press enter from keyboard while typing It is scrolling parent scrollview

Comment: @KishanVaghela I have the same issue.. How did you resolve it?

Comment: Write full `onTouch` as it above answer is removed, no one will understood how to set `onTouch`

Comment: onTouch method worked for me, without adding properties in layout.

Answer (score 23):

**Kotlin version**

Add the following lines to the EditText in your xml:

```
android:overScrollMode="always"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Add this to the Activity/Fragment:

```
myEditText.setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
   view.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
   if ((event.action and MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
       view.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
   }
   return@setOnTouchListener false
}
```

Answer (score 12):

you should use NestedScrollView class. This class support child scrolling inside parent scrolling. This class can be a child or a parent.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView         
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#d6d8d9">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="512"
                android:text=" your content"/>
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_below="@id/ll_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="#d6d8d9">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="your content"
                android:maxLines="512"/>    
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>       
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: This works and is simple, however the underline of TextEdit gets scrolled too, so it's better to use the XML + setOnTouchListener solution (although it's a less clean code).

Answer (score 12):

**Use this code it's working**

**In XML**

```
android:singleLine="false"
android:overScrollMode="always"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

**In programming**

```
edittext.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        if (view.getId() == R.id.edittext) {
            view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Building upon the answer by @Ayman Mahgoub and @Hariharan.  The solution worked great except while scrolling the edit text there is no scroll momentum.  As soon as the finger lifts up, the scrolling immediately stops.

To gain scroll momentum wrap a scrollview around the EditText and let the EditText's height wrap content (set minHeight if you'd like).  Remove the following lines from the edit text:

```
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:scrollbars="vertical" 
android:overScrollMode="always"
```

Now the nested ScrollView wrapped around the EditText takes care of the scrolling.  Update the onTouch handler to take into account the updated view hierarchy:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    v.getParent().getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            v.getParent().getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            break;
    }
    return false;
```

Be warned, this solution is now tightly coupled to the view hierarchy.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/atoennis/7549fba2634d0abccddf

Comment: My answer above is dated.  @HungNM2 has the more modern and correct answer.

Comment: I have a `ScrollView` which contains several view, and just one of them is a `EditText`. Does this solution only assumes one `EditText` inside the `ScrollView`? Or adding an extra `ScrollView` just to wrap the `EditText`?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is by doing Extention in Kotlin:

First add this extension:

```
fun EditText.enableScrollText()
{
    overScrollMode = View.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS
    scrollBarStyle = View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET
    isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = true
    setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
        if (view is EditText) {
            if(!view.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                view.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
                when (event.action and MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> view.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
                }
            }
        }
        false
    }
}
```

and finally easily call this for your edittext:

```
editText.enableScrollText();
```

This extention works well in any case like inside `ScrollView` or `RecyclerView` or `BottomSheet`

Answer (score 2):

I would vote up the updated answer provided by @Ayman Mahgoub, but I do not have a high enough reputation. His code works. I had to change return true to return false. You put the .setOnTouchListener() method in your java class and put the three lines:

```
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:scrollbars="vertical" 
android:overScrollMode="always"
```

in the corresponding xml file. You can see the implementation in the android emulator, and on the android phone you use for testing. Thank you so much @Ayman Mahgoub and @Hariharan!

Answer (score 2):

This will scroll the `EditText` and make it editable:

First in the XML file, add this:

```
android:overScrollMode="always"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Then in the Java file, add this:

```
EditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
           view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
           switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
                  view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                   return true;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS:
                   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                   imm.showSoftInput(EditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
           }
           return false;
       }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Below Answer will help you to make Edit Text scrollable inside Scroll View and also show Count of it.

1.Make one rectangle_with_border_gray.xml file in @drawable folder.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <stroke android:color="#7f848686"
            android:width="0.01dp"/>
    </shape>
```

2.Then, In @layout write below code in scroll view.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none">

             <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/sv_profile_creation_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/LL_optional_message"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_optional_message_title"
                        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_with_border_gray"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="@dimen/margin_02_dp">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_optional_message"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="100dp"
                            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            android:hint="@string/why_not_leave_a_message"
                            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                            android:isScrollContainer="true"
                            android:maxLines="5"
                            android:overScrollMode="always"
                            android:padding="8dp"
                            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                            android:scrollbars="vertical"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorEditTextHintNormal"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/colorEditTextHint"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/margin_14_dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_description_count"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/LL_optional_message"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_16_dp"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="0/200"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorLittleDarkGray"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/margin_12_dp"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />

         </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

3.Then, Inside your Activity or Fragment write below code:

```
TextView tv_description_count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_description_count);

EditText et_optional_message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_optional_message);

private void makeScrollable(){
            et_optional_message.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
            et_optional_message.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
                            view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                            return true;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS:
                            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            imm.showSoftInput(et_optional_message, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

 private final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //This sets a textview to the current length
                tv_description_count.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        };
```

Happy Coding......

Answer (score 0):

First create a custom Scrollview class as given below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class MyCustomScrollview extends ScrollView {

    public VerticalScrollview(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public VerticalScrollview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public VerticalScrollview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: DOWN super false" );
                super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                return false; // redirect MotionEvents to ourself

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: CANCEL super false" );
                super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: UP super false" );
                return false;

            default: Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: " + action ); break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onTouchEvent. action: " + ev.getAction() );
        return true;
    }
}
```

2. Now in the activity or fragment where you are using the EditText, write the following code for the EditText object that you want to scroll inside the Scrollview :

   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.MotionEvent;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.EditText;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ```
   EditText et;
   VerticalScrollview sv;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       init();
   }

   private void init() {
       sv = findViewById(R.id.sv);
       et = findViewById(R.id.et);
       et.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               if (v.getId() == R.id.sv) {
                   v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                   switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                           v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                           break;
                   }
               }
               return false;
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   }

3.The follwing xml is given below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.example.ayan.scrollableedittext.VerticalScrollview
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sv">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="600dp"
                android:gravity="center">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                    android:gravity="start" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.example.ayan.scrollableedittext.VerticalScrollview>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Hariharan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24428854/2914140), [vovahost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49694427/2914140) I got the same solution, but added `performClick()` to avoid a warning.

EditText (XML):

```
android:overScrollMode="always"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Code:

```
edit_text.setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
    view.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
    if ((event.action and MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL) {
        view.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
    } else {
        performClick()
    }
    return@setOnTouchListener false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this method in main activity:

It worked for me in Fragment

```
 @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            View v = getCurrentFocus();
            if (v instanceof EditText) {
                Rect outRect = new Rect();
                v.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);
                if (!outRect.contains((int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY())) {
                    v.clearFocus();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
```