# Mutiline edittext inside recyclerview is not scrolling properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I have a `Edittext` view to post comments on the feeds which are in `Edittext`. when i put a lot of text inside `Edittext` and scrollbar appears i cannot scroll my `Edittext's` text content. `Recyclerview` scrolls up when i want to scroll in `Edittext`. How can i solve this. Please suggest.

Comment: *look at here:* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428808/how-to-scroll-the-edittext-inside-the-scrollview *and* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314836/recycler-view-inside-nestedscrollview-causes-scroll-to-start-in-the-middle/40474022#40474022

Answer (score 4):

```
textInputField.setOnTouchListener { v, _ ->
  v.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
  false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always a challenge to solve problems without seeing some code to reference, but one guesses might be:

- The focus might be taken off of the `EditText` from the `RecyclerView`, you can  call setFocusable(boolean) on your `EditText` to gain focus from touch input

Checkout the Google docs on `View` under Focus Handling and Touch Mode to see if it helps solve your problem.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Answer (score -2):

Use `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` , `android:scrollbars="vertical"` , `android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"` on your `EditText`.

Comment: this is not working in recyclerview edit text. i want to add text in edittext recyclerview and saved in it when i swipe up or down and comeback at same position my text appear.