# Problem with implement scratch-card in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I have problem with add to scratchcard in RecyclerView
because of when i scratch the cards vertically, it was not scratch but it was scroll up down
how to solve it ?
Please help me to solve this issue...

this is my RecyclerView

```
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rcvScratch"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:isScrollContainer="false"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                app:fastScrollEnabled="false"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_scratch_card" />
```

Comment: you can do like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24428854/10989990, where you can set `TouchListener` on `scratch card view`

Comment: not working @Priyankagb

Comment: use `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` instead of `MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL`

Comment: post your viewholders touch listener

Comment: Did you find any solution?