# ScrollView blocking its parents click listener

Tags: android, scrollview

I am using scroll view inside RelativeLayout and I am assigning onClickLIstener to RelativeLayout.

I am using following code.
Layoutfile

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/row2_lnr_layout_ver">


                     <ScrollView
                           android:id="@+id/row2_scrollview"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical" 
                        android:fillViewport="true">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/sa_sub_txt_view_2"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.4"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="hjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black">
                        </TextView>

                   </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java File in OnCreate()

```
((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.row2_lnr_layout_ver)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("MainActivity", "onSmartActionClicked");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        }
    });
```

So when I click on TextView or scrollview, it does not show Toast. But when I remove scroll view and click on textview, then it works fine. Can anybody tell me why this strange behavior while using ScrollView??

Comment: Have you set any child click listener of RelativeLayout ?

Comment: Have you try adding android:clickable="true" to your RelativeLayout?

Comment: @HareshChhelana: nope

Comment: @peguerosdc: I tried adding that, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try adding the following touch listener for the TextView and after that, set the onclick Listener for the Textview rather than giving it to the Relative Layout.

```
private OnTouchListener textViewTouchListener= new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            break;
        }

        v.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: I wanted to add click listener to RelativeLayout demanded by my app. So I cant use it to listener to TextView..

Answer (score 0):

Try requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent from ViewParent: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean)

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
  }
```

[android scrollable textview inside scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422771/android-scrollable-textview-inside-scrollview)