# Can not scroll my TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, scroll

I read about some ways, how to make a `TextView` scrollable. 
Here is my some code from my Fragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_handlungsleitfaden, container, false);

        // 1. pass context and data to the custom adapter
        adapter = new AdapterHandlungsleitfaden(getContext(), generateData());

        // if extending Activity 2. Get ListView from activity_main.xml
        final ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // 3. setListAdapter
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                models.add(new ListItemDataHandlungsleitfaden(R.drawable.uncheck,"" + counter + "." + value, "" + counter));
                counter++;

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ITEM WIRD ERWEITERT!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        //initialize TextView - Title
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title_handlungsleitfaden);
        title.setText("Das ist nur ein Test!");

        //initialize TextView - Content
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_handlungsleitfaden);
        textView.setText("HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!" +
                "HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!" +
                "HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!HALLO WELT!" +
                "DU NE HAHA GENIAL!");

        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        return view;
    }
```

As you can see, I used this method:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

on this way, I tried to make my `TextView` scrollable.

Here is my xml-layout for the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".uiFragments.HandlungsleitfadenFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="250dp"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title_handlungsleitfaden"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_handlungsleitfaden"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_border" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bild_handlungsleitfaden"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/homer"/>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <VideoView
                        android:id="@+id/video_handlungsleitfaden"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handlungsleitfaden_btn"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="7dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="weiter" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I can scroll the display, but I can not scroll in the TextView..because, when I try to do it, I can only scroll my "whole" display" like the textbox, title, image and video. But I want a way, also to scroll this display like I can do now AND also the `TextView`, which is inside the `ScrollView`.

If someone can help me, I would be very happy!

Thanks in advice!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422771/android-scrollable-textview-inside-scrollview

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set these properties in `xml` file on `TextView` for which you want scroll.

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

Here at the place of `AN_INTEGER` you can put any integer like : 1,2,3,,,,100 etc.

And then, in your `Activity` class use this

`textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`